# SSIS lookup "cannot map the input column, because data types do not match"

Tags: sql-server, csv, ssis, etl, lookup

I am loading a CSV file.  I need to do a lookup on a value in a SQL Table.   The CSV column dt_string 35, while the SQL column is an nvarchar(35).  I am pretty new to SSIS so I don't know where to do a convert or cast so the lookup will work.   I have googled it for several different answers but I can find a good step by step tutorial on how to do it.   Thank in advance.

I tried Data Conversion.

I expect to be able to look up a Product and get the ProductID,  so I can insert the ProductID into another table.

Comment: I think in the data source for the file, you can definitely the data type so you won't have to do a second conversion.

Comment: You can cast your lookup query or you can import from flat file as western

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be easier to change the column data type from the Flat File Connection Manager:

1. Open the Flat File Connection Manager
2. Go To Advanced Tab
3. Click on the Column and change the Data Type from `DT_STR` to `DT_WSTR`

Comment: Thank you for the easy step by step answer!

Comment: @JustinWhitfield Note that the other answer is correct but this is an easiest approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add a **Data Conversion Transformation** to convert the column from `DT_STR` to `DT_WSTR` or you can add a **Derived Column Transformation** and use a similar expression to convert to nvarchar:

```
(DT_WSTR,35)[Product]
```

**Additional Information**

- [UNDERSTAND DATA CONVERSION IN SSIS WITH AN EXAMPLE](http://www.learnmsbitutorials.net/dataconversion-ssis.php)
- [SSIS Data Conversion](https://www.tutorialgateway.org/ssis-data-conversion/)
- [Derived Column Transformation in SSIS](https://www.tutorialgateway.org/derived-column-transformation-in-ssis/)
- [How to Use Derived Column Transformation in SSIS with Example - SSIS](https://mindmajix.com/ssis/how-to-use-derived-column-transformation-in-ssis-example)